# Missing '.NET Portable Subset' project reference on colleagues machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

A colleague just pulled down the latest changes but a portable core library I setup won't build, it complains that System.Linq is not known and VS says we're probably missing a library reference.

Under references of the Portable Library, the '.NET Portable Subset' reference is not listed. This is the only reference it should have so effectively my references are empty.

My colleague is running the latest Visual Studio 2012 like me. The '.NET Portable Subset' reference isn't a typical DLL so I can't add it on his machine - I guess something's up with his dev box.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Install [VS 2012 Update 2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38188) on both your machines.

Caveat: If you install VS 2012 Update 2 **after** the WP8 SDK, you will need to repair the Update 2 installation if you get errors about types in System.Net.  See Issue 2 in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840147)

Explanation: The WP8 SDK added additional portable profiles (basically combinations of platforms you can target) which weren't included in VS2012 RTM.  Those additional profiles were included in VS2012 Update 2 so you can install.

Answer (score 1):

When you setup the portable library, you would have chosen the supported platforms, such as the minimum version of Silverlight and XBox etc.

It's likely that one of these SDKs is missing on the other PC. What may be a bigger problem is that if your colleague is on Windows 7, he cannot install the Windows Phone 8 SDK, in which case on your side, in the portable project properties, Library tab, change the minimum supported phone to WP 7.5, commit and push and pull and your colleague should be good to go.

With love, yourself.

Comment: VS2012 Update 2 includes the updates to the portable profiles which came in the WP8 SDK.  So if you both install that it should fix the issue.

Comment: Dan - stick that in as an answer and I'll give you to green tick - its a better answer for the future.